# In Firefox, how to prevent page reload on return to previous page

Tags: firefox

When I visit a site such as NYtimes.com and then click on an article, returning to the main page (using a two-finger swipe, the back button or backspace) causes Firefox to reload the page however short the time since it was last loaded. How can I stop this behaviour and get a copy of what was visible before?

Safari does this somewhat better; swiping two fingers to go back reveals the previous page as it was - Safari then reloads the images (maybe the text too, but it is not so obvious.

I imagine this has to do with cache control and whether components of the page or the page itself have expired. I'd like to be able to override that.

Comment: This is not as simple as you might think. A modern web page often includes things like network connections that can't easily be restored without running the code that generated them in the first place, and that code does what it does.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to open links in a new tab. This can be quite a bit more memory intensive if you open many such tabs, but as you close each one you'll find the previous page still loaded.

I'm not certain how well this will work with hand gestures. Or even if firefox has a hand gesture for "close tab". On firefox on android the gesture for back also closes tabs if the current tab has no history. Additionally, opening links in a new tab typically requires a right click... so that's a two-finger press for gestures if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

By default Firefox does store cache for all parts of a webpage that it can, although on a lot of secure https sites, like paypal, it is blocked from doing so for security reasons. If you search something in google though, go to a website, then disconnect from the internet and go back to the google search, you will notice the page will load all the content that was stored as cache.
So even though the page reloads, it will not reload the cached content as long as it detects no updates. Even so, if you want to stop this, then try editing browser.sessionhistory.max_total_viewers or browser.cache.check_doc_frequency by going to about:config.
Hope this helped!